# Can I use the Xamarin.Forms RepeaterView with .NET MAUI?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I'm making a quiz application with .NET MAUI, and I want to use the approach of RepeaterView of Xamarin.Forms to display my quiz questions one by one. Can I use the approach of RepeaterView with .NET MAUI?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: BindableLayout is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason mentioned in his comment, you can use a [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout) in combination with a StackLayout (as well as *VerticalStackLayout* or *HorizontalStackLayout*, which are the same thing just with the `Orientation` property implicitly set) in MAUI (just like in Xamarin.Forms), e.g.:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout 
    Spacing="30" 
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"> 
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MyItem"> 
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <!-- etc. -->
            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate> 
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

This will display a collection of objects as Labels spaced 30 units apart vertically, in this case an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` called `MyCollection` where the `MyItem` type has a property called `Name`:

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This does pretty much the same thing as the third-party [RepeaterView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CustomControls.RepeaterView) component for Xamarin.Forms, which you're probably referring to, except it comes already built-in with XF and MAUI, you can use it using XAML-only and you don't need to install a third-party package.

A minor difference worth noting is that the RepeaterView control comes with an optional, built-in separator, which you would have to implement yourself with the above approach.

Alternatively, nobody stops you from porting the [RepeaterView code](https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin-Custom-Controls/tree/master/src/Xamarin.CustomControls.Repeater) to MAUI.

Comment: I will never understand why repeater view is still a thing after so many years of bindable layout being public

Comment: Well, it's convenient, I suppose. I mostly use the BindableLayout by now myself, but the RepeaterView has its perks, too. Especially the built-in separator is quite useful.